# Dplyr - keep n biggest Groups

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `dplyr` how can I filter the `n` biggest groups with regards to observations?

I can do this...

```
mtcars %>%
    count(gear)

  gear  n
1    3 15
2    4 12
3    5  5

mtcars %>%
    semi_join(mtcars %>% count(gear) %>% slice(1:2)
              , by = "gear")
```

but it seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

You current solution seems pretty good. Here is one more alternative.

```
filter(mtcars, gear %in% count(mtcars, gear, sort = TRUE)$gear[1:2])
```

Comment: This works fine, but sadly it also doesn't look very good. :( I was so hoping for an appealing solution.

Comment: You could write your own function if this is something you do repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the joins you can do this:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(dense_rank(-n) <= 2)
```

Because you need both a grouped operation (to count) and an global operation (compare counts between groups), it's going to be hard to get it really short (unless you build a custom function).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to avoid the join.

```
n <- 2

mtcars %>%
  filter(gear %in% vctrs::vec_count(gear)$key[1:n])
```

Or, without `vctrs`.

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(gear %in% names(sort(table(gear), decreasing = TRUE))[1:n])
```

Comment: The first one works, but the second filters the `n` **smallest** groups, not the biggest. Maybe you can change that in the answer.

Comment: @Georgery, it was missing `decreasing = TRUE`. I've updated my answer.